# Pause and reverse CSS animation on hover

Tags: css, animation

I have a 11 frame png spritesheet. When you hover it will play the animation until the last frame and then pause, and when you hover out it will reverse the animation back to the first frame. I have this so far:

```css
.intern {
  width: 328px;
  height: 187px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/zNsJCnM.png");
  -webkit-animation: in 0.5s steps(11);
}
.intern:hover {
  -webkit-animation: out 0.5s steps(11);
}
@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0px -2057px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -2057px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intern"></div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/os2jm4h5/

Can someone help me out? I would like to do this with CSS (no JavaScript please) and preferably should use only one `div`.

Comment: Please include your relevant code, rather than just linking the jsfiddle.  Also, while you say what you want, and apparently have some code, you don't make it clear what your code *currently* does, and in what way(s) it is lacking.  Can you summarize your problem?

Comment: I do not think you can do this, because you only have 2 states within CSS: a normal state and a hover state. You can not manipulate this with CSS. CSS has not the capability to look when a user moves his mouse away from the image and stop the animation at a certain point and finish the animation. You nee javascript for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with a few changes to CSS:

- Add `background-position: 0px -1683px;` to `.intern:hover`. This will ensure that the animation "pauses" on the final frame. Currently when the hover animation finishes `background-position` goes back to `0px 0px;`.
- Reverse `background-position` in `from` and `to` for `@-webkit-keyframes in`
- Reverse `background-position` in `0%` and `100%` for`@-webkit-keyframes out`

```css
.intern {
  width: 328px;
  height: 187px;
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/zNsJCnM.png");
  -webkit-animation: in 0.5s steps(11);
}
.intern:hover {
  -webkit-animation: out 0.5s steps(11);
  background-position: 0px -1683px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes in {
  from {
    background-position: 0px -2057px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    background-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0px -2057px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="intern"></div>
```

*Note that `background-position: 0px -1683px;` is used because the last image in the sprite sheet (`background-position: 0px -2057px;`) is actually a copy of the first frame.*